# How do I generate multiple hashes that can be resolved to a single value?

Tags: algorithms, hashing

I need multiple "random" URLs that just mask the original URL, i.e.:

```
/ABC
/CBA
/CAB
```

All resolve to `/6`

I came up with matching a letter to a number and then you can sum them to the single value.

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
...

/ABC = A + B + C = 6
/CBA = C + B + A = 6
/CAB = C + A + B = 6
...
```

Is there a name for this? It doesn't seem to be **reversible hashing.**

Is there an existing algorithm to generate+resolve them?

Comment: The correct name is hash collision. Hash collision is a bad thing for hash functions; therefore, well-designed hash functions will minimize hash collision. Based on your usage, you probably aren't looking for a "hash function" per se, but instead try to look for an information concealment function, preferably one that doesn't require maintaining a database of keys and values.

Comment: You might also need to think about whether security is a concern, i.e. would it matter if your scheme is trivially breakable by an outsider.

Comment: Hashing **always** involves collisions. If it didn't, it would be encryption. The trick about hashing is to design your hash function so that *accidental* collisions are unlikely.

Comment: No, security in my case was not an issue, it's just a way to share the same resource while making it look "personal" or made just for the user.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a hash function for strings for which character order does not matter. As others have said it would not be a good one. Maybe give more details about what you are trying to achieve because there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: It's called encryption. You get different ciphertext if you use different nonces/IVs.

Comment: That's not a hash, it's obfuscation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this, it only works on numbers (a string-to-number conversion could happen outside if necessary).

It converts the number to binary and then maps lowercase letters that are either odd (a, c, e, ...) or even (b, d, f, ...) to each 0 or 1 respectively. So

```
74 =   1001010 =   "baababa"
74 =   1001010 =   "pcgtghy"
74 =  01001010 =  "etcetera"
```

This is the code in Javascript

```js
const a = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
const length = 'z'.charCodeAt(0) - a;

function padLeft (string, len){
    while(string.length < len) { string = 0 + string; }
    return string;
}
function decode (val) {
    return (val.charCodeAt(0) - a) % 2;
}
function encode (odd) {
    // generate a random letter in the available range
    // but make sure it's odd or even
    return String.fromCharCode(a + Math.floor(length * Math.random() / 2) * 2 + parseInt(odd, 10));
}
function generate (number, minLength = 0) {
    return padLeft(number.toString(2), minLength).split('').map(encode).join('');
}
function solve (code) {
    return parseInt(code.split('').map(decode).join(''), 2);
}
```

And this is the usage, it also accepts a minimum length parameter

```js
code = generate(74);     console.log(code, solve(code));
code = generate(74, 5);  console.log(code, solve(code));
code = generate(74, 10); console.log(code, solve(code));
code = generate(74, 20); console.log(code, solve(code));
```

Also on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-encoder)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by the other commentors you are not really looking for a hash function, but instead just need a simple encryption. As you state that trivial security breaches are of no consequence, you can rely on very simply substitution ciphers. It will look like gibberish, but still work out nicely.

The name that comes closest to such a thing is the generation of cipher texts in encryption. "Cipher" simply means that unreadable gibberish that you get after you encrypted your precious text with a secret key. In your case, since you only want that cipher you can just include the key, trivially breaking the encryption, and for your interpretation end you just extract the key and de-crypt the remaining part, which would be the cipher.

Note that this approach when combined with an alphanumeric encoding like BASE64 can be applied with pretty much any encryption algorithm you fancy. Roll your own (viable, since you don't need it to actually be safe), or take a really strong standard implementation of something like AES. Doesn't really matter.

Here's an example: Let's say you just want to use the characters A-Z and you perform a [rotation cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) (like ROT-13), such that the first character is the "key". You can take any simple URL-word like "DATA" and rotate it based on an additional first character. Let's interpret A as 0, then B is a rotation of 1, so D would become the letter E (one after D), A becomes B, and so on. The character Z becomes A again via a simple modulo operation.

This immediately gives you 25 different variations of "DATA" which look "personalized" yet "unintelligible". Something like this:

AEBUB
BFCVC
...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using hashing, you might need a dictionary to resolve a hashed URL to a normal URL; e.g.

```
Dictionary<int, Uri> urlHashes;
```

So that you can do:

```
Uri originalURL = urlHashes[hashKey];
```

Otherwise you will have to check the received hash against every URL that exists in your scope; e.g.:

```
List<Uri> allUrls;
foreach (Uri u in allUrls)
{
     int hash = u.GetHashCode();
     if (hash == hashKey)
     {
         return u;
     }
}
throw new InvallidUrl()
```

There are two options to create multiple keys pointing to te same URL:

1. Add a random number or string to the URL and calculate the hash over the combination; e.g.:

   ```
   const int mySecretRandomPrime = 3943;
   int randomNumber = new Random().Next(1000);
   int urlHash = (url.GetHashCode() * mySecretRandomPrime) + randomNumber;

   return urlHash;
   ```

   If you store the keys–URL pairs you can lookup the original URL via the composite hash that you have stored.

   Or, if you do not store all provided url hashes, you can require the client to sent both the combined `urlHash` and `randomBumber` to you and you can iterate over the list of known URLs, calculate the combined hash and return the matching URL; e.g.:

   ```
   List<Uri> allUrls;
   const int mySecretRandomPrime = 3943;

   foreach (Uri u in allUrls)
   {
       int hash = (url.GetHashCode() * mySecretRandomPrime) + randomNumber;
       if (hash == hashKey)
       {
           return u;
       }
   }
   throw new InvallidUrl()
   ```
2. If you opt to store key–url-pairs, you can also leave out the URL hashes completely and just return (cryptologically) random GUIDs/UUIDs.